# Remote debug .net core app running in Azure App Services For Containers

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core

I am using Azure App Services For Linux Containers.  I have followed their instructions to enable SSH (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#enable-ssh).

This works but it doesn't expose SSH on a public port.  You have to go through their interface so I have no clue how I am meant to setup up VSDBG.

The remote debugging instructions are here: https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/wiki/Offroad-Debugging-of-.NET-Core-on-Linux---OSX-from-Visual-Studio

It works by connecting visual studio to a process on server via SSH.

Seeing as Azure is a Microsoft product I must assume there is a way with their ecosystem to connect to a debugging session but I can't find the doc that says how to do it.

How do I debug linux containers in App Services?

edit:

I discovered cloud explorer in VS2017 and it has an attach option but it gives error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710023): Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named 'gardner.azurewebsites.net'.  The input data was not in the expected format or did not have the expected value.

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.Internal.IDebuggerInternal120.ConnectToServer(String szServerName, VsDebugRemoteConnectOptions[] pConnectOptions, CONNECT_REASON ConnectReason, Int32 fIncrementUsageCount, IDebugCoreServer3& ppServer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Azure.MicrosoftWeb.Operations.RemoteDiagnosticsSessionBase.ConnectToServer(String site, String user, String password)
```

I think I need to modify container

edit:

I found example for making it work on windows image: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2019/01/30/debugging-docker-containers-attaching/

I need to figure out how to do same thing in linux

Comment: Looks like official response is 'not supported' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/374384/how-to-remote-debugging-net-5-docker-container-app.html